# Query with default partitions in Mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql, partition

I have a table 'transaction' with created_time, I create partition by created_time per month (202001, 202002, 202003, 202004..). So I would like query this table with default partition instead I have to specify which partitions in query. How can I query without pruning in where condition and without 'partition(p1)' keyword?

Expect:

```
select * from transaction; -> It will return only partition 202003, 202004 if i set 202003, 202004 as default partitions.
```

Comment: "default partition" - what do you mean?

Comment: Instead of 'select * from transaction partition(202003, 202004)', I only use 'select * from transaction'. I will set this default partition for master DB, and don't set it for Replica DB. So, realtime transaction will use in 3 months but report query will use in 2 years.